# Get array entries from another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-mobile

I have the following program structure:

index.html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="first.js"></script>
      <script src="second.js"></script>
  </head>
...</html>
```

first.js:

```
"use strict";
var array = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#xy").on("tap", function () {
   array.push(new arrayItem());
} ...
```

second.js:

```
console.log(array);
```

In first.js, I push some objects to the array, but console.log in second.js says, that my array is empty. What am I doing wrong? Thanks...

Comment: are you sure you are logging after you trigger the ```tap``` event?

Comment: First is not executing until document is ready. Second is executing immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previous users have stated, your console.log is being run immediately while your array is being populated after the document has been fully loaded. However, even if you were to have your console.log run when the document is loaded, it still won't see your variable. What you want to do is when on your 'tap' event, send the array to a function that's defined in second.js like so:

in first.js

```
"use strict";
var array = [];

$(document).ready(function () {

$("#xy").on("tap", function () {
   array.push(new arrayItem());
   someFunction(array);
}
```

in second.js

```
function someFunction(array) {
    console.log(array);
    // Do the rest of your code that requires 'array' here
}
```

This way, every time you fire the on tap event, someFunction is handed the array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log(array)` is likely being called before the document is ready, which is when your main application code runs.

You should either move the `console.log` to the main file after your data has been added to the array, or perhaps use callbacks or events to log it after the main function has completed.

Comment: The entries of my array should be available in second.js. How could I manage this using callbacks?

Comment: It looks like someone else has just posted an example of this!